# Pass variables into script block powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I seem to have a lot of trouble understanding how to get this working. I am trying to gather all variables up front that way I can call psexec and pass those variables to it in a scriptblock.

The reason I am using psexec is due to the fact I have old 2003 servers without powershell installed. My goal was to have powershell multithread out against a list of servers in a text file and spawn processes in a manner below.

```
    #Gather info
    $servers = "test1234"
    $userName = Read-host "What is the user name?"
    $userPassword = Read-host "What is the user password?"

    $scriptBlockwork = {c:\scripts\message\psexec.exe "$servers" -u domain\$userName -p $userPassword -c InstallMShotfix.cmd -f InstallMShotfix.cmd}.GetNewClosure()
    & $scriptBlockwork
    echo $scriptBlockwork
```

Why does the script block not take the variables defined even when using .GetNewClosure()

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear from your question in which order you want to bind the parameters, but for a proper closure:

```
$PartialInstaller = {
    param($servers)
    return {
        param($userName,$userPassword)
        c:\scripts\message\psexec.exe "$servers" -u domain\$userName -p $userPassword -c InstallMShotfix.cmd -f InstallMShotfix.cmd
    }.GetNewClosure()
}

$Installer = &$PartialInstaller $servers
$Result = &Installer "username","password"
```

---

Alternatively, the call operator (`&`) supports [splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx) as well:

```
$ScriptArguments = @{}
$ScriptArguments.servers = "test1234"
$ScriptArguments.userName = Read-host "What is the user name?"
$ScriptArguments.userPassword = Read-host "What is the user password?"

$Work = {
    param($servers,$userName,$userPassword)
    c:\scripts\message\psexec.exe "$servers" -u domain\$userName -p $userPassword -c InstallMShotfix.cmd -f InstallMShotfix.cmd
}

& $Work @ScriptArguments
```

Comment: With this if I i want to call $work, it would not & $work and @scriptsarguments . Trying something like `$work2= {$work = {{ param($server,$Credential)
          echo $server $Credential | out-file C:\echoplease.txt -NoClobber}& $work $ScriptArguments}}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -AsJob -ScriptBlock $work2 ` Didnt seem to work

Comment: Oh sorry, neglected to address your requirement for a proper Closure. My example must be very confusing then, I'll update it

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but I've never been able to get `.getnewclosure()` to work for that.

Fortunately `[scriptblock]::Create()` provides an workaround:

```
#Gather info
    $servers = "test1234"
    $userName = Read-host "What is the user name?"
    $userPassword = Read-host "What is the user password?"

    $scriptBlockwork = 
    [scriptblock]::Create(@"
    c:\scripts\message\psexec.exe "$servers" -u domain\$userName -p $userPassword -c InstallMShotfix.cmd -f InstallMShotfix.cmd
"@)
    & $scriptBlockwork
    echo $scriptBlockwork
```

Answer (score 0):

[invoke-command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx) on TechNet.

Example 2 and Example 5 are each similar to your example.

Example 3 and Example 4 would allow you to do it without psexec, but you'll need WinRM enabled on the remote machine.  These are especially useful if you need to execute a number of commands.

Also research [Get-Credential](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849815.aspx) for prompting for authentification.  Depending on the environment (information security policy in your organization, etc.), you may be able to store the credentials in a file (encrypted format) and reuse them in scripts.  Bare minimum, you won't be passing admin credentials over the wire in the clear.

TL;DR Invoke-Command is your friend.  Get-Credential is more secure than Read-Host.

```
$Credential = $get-credential
foreach ($Server in $Serverlist) {
    $scriptBlockwork = { psexec $Server -c InstallMShotfix.cmd -f InstallMShotfix.cmd }
    Invoke-Command -credential $Credential -scriptblock $scriptBlockwork
}
```

This will run your psexec command with the credentials you enter.  They need the right to run psexec locally and to run the cmd file on the remote machine.  Populate $Serverlist by reading in a text file or statically defining it above.

Comment: Just as an aside, consider installing WMF on your 2003 servers, so you can simplify this to:

    `Invoke-Command -ComputerName server01 -Credential domain01\user01 -ScriptBlock { InstallMShotfix.cmd }`  In this case `Invoke-Command` replaces psexec.

Comment: This will wait until each session is complete before proceeding, and not thread out. If i had 25 servers in that list it would take a long time to complete. Right?

Comment: @james I think that using the `-asjob` switch parameter in `invoke-command` can do the trick,

Comment: I was worried because `-asjob` starts a PS job on the target computer.  Documentation says "Remote" but it should say "target".  

The switch `-asjob` is not allowed without a target.  But there's an easy workaround.

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -AsJob -ScriptBlock ...`